# How do I recode the logic of the .IF instructions using CMP and conditional jump instructions

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, masm32

```
.data
TRUE = 1
FALSE = 0
gradeAverage  DWORD 275 ; test value
credits       DWORD 12  ; test value
OkToRegister  BYTE ?

.code
main PROC
mov OkToRegister,FALSE

mov eax, gradeAverage
cmp eax, 350
ja l1

L1: mov OkToRegister,TRUE

mov eax, gradeAverage
cmp eax, 250
ja l2
L2: mov ebx,credits
    cmp ebx,16
    jbe l3
    L3: mov OkToRegister,TRUE

mov ebx,credits
cmp ebx,12
jbe l4
L4: mov OkToRegister,TRUE  

main ENDP
```

This is my attempt at changing the logic to jump statements, but after running this I received a logic error, which I can see possible because I am not sure how to say .ELSEIF with jumps. If possible, please help me understand how to fix my code to make it work. By the way, yes this is for school, and yes this is homework. I'm not looking for an answer, just some helpful hints to point me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

```
.IF gradeAverage > 350
   mov OkToRegister,TRUE
.ELSEIF (gradeAverage > 250) && (credits <= 16)
   mov OkToRegister,TRUE
.ELSEIF (credits <= 12)
   mov OkToRegister,TRUE
.ENDIF
```

This is the .IF/.ELSEIF logic that is being used in the original program.

Comment: `ja l1` will jump to label `l1` when CF=0 and ZF=0 (IIRC, simply "unsigned above" result of `cmp`). And in any other case it will skip to next instruction... which is at address `l1:` ... so you did create `jmp l1` effectively, not having second code branch. I would suggest to use meaningful label names first, like `setRegisterToTrue:` ... and then it will probably make more sense, how many code branches you need. Don't rewrite that macro code, just extract the logic and write it in clean simple way.

Comment: wow, thanks man. I can't believe I overthought it like that. Once I set the code labels to meaningful ones it became much easier to visual the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I tried some masm32 14 yrs before. I guess the trick was to jump appropriately.

```
.code
main PROC
mov OkToRegister,FALSE

mov eax, gradeAverage
cmp eax, 350
ja LT
mov eax, gradeAverage
cmp eax, 250
jbe L1 
mov ebx,credits
cmp ebx,16
jbe LT  
L1:
mov ebx,credits
cmp ebx,12
ja LF
LT: mov OkToRegister,TRUE  
LF:
main ENDP
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out and you helped me make sure I was correct!

Comment: You are welcome, it is nice to see some assembly anytime.